# Delete few rows from db table

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-delete

Right now in my code I check if row count is greater than 100 then I delete all the rows by using `context.getContentResolver().delete( tablename, null, null );`.

But I want to delete rows from 1 to 80 and after deleting those rows, offset( rename ) the last left over rows from 80 to 100 -> 1 to 20 and if I add any rows in that  table the primary key ID should start from 21.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: when You delete 20-100 Do you want change id of first to 0

Comment: I want to delete 1- 80 and remaining 80 - 100 should be renamed to 1 to 20 and newly added rows should continue with 21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the primary key of your table is called _id and is set to autoincrement. Delete the 80 rows you don't want:

```
String query = "DELETE FROM " + tablename + " WHERE _id <= 80";
context.getContentResolver().execSQL(query);
```

For those rows that remain (that are ids 81 - 100), update the id by subtracting 80 so they'll then go from 1 - 20:

```
query = "UPDATE " + tablename + " SET _id = _id - 80";
context.getContentResolver().execSQL(query);
```

Update the entry in the sqlite_sequence table for this table. Set seq to that of the last id on the table:

```
query = "UPDATE sqlite_sequence SET seq = 20 WHERE name = '" + tablename + "'";
context.getContentResolver().execSQL(query);
```

When you next insert, _id will continue from 21.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
for (int i=20 , i<101 ; i++)
{    
    database.delete(tableName,"ID = " +String.valueof(i), null);
}
```

Comment: Sorry my initial post was not clear.. I updated you the latest

Answer (score -1):

You should never change values of your primary key, because his value need to be unique. Use another field do to that ("row_number" for example).

Request to delete rows between 0 & 80 (included)

```
db.beginTransaction();
db.delete("TABLE_NAME", "row_number <= 80" , null);
db.setTransactionSuccessful();
db.endTransaction();
```

Request to update rows between 81 & 100 to 0-20

```
db.beginTransaction();
db.execSQL("UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME + " SET row_number = row_number - 80;");
db.setTransactionSuccessful();
db.endTransaction();
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, it's more of a comment on a side-topic the OP mentioned. Could you elaborate more and modify your answer to better target the question?